# How to decompress bytes from a zip file in C#

Tags: c#, zip, byte, compression

My program handles zip files with encrypted headers, it decrypts the headers and shows the info. Now I want to view the pictures within the zip file in a picturebox so I have to decompress the files into a memorystream.

I have all the bytes of the compressed files. Wich means: header, compressed data, extra length.

How can I decompress these bytes so I can view the file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use the [`ZipArchive`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.compression.ziparchive.aspx) class to read the compressed data, since it appears you're reading valid zip files.

If you're using .NET 4 or older, you'll have to use a third-party library, like [DotNetZip](http://dotnetzip.codeplex.com/) and its [`ZipInputStream`](http://dotnetzip.herobo.com/DNZHelp/html/a1a897db-bc65-2b08-875c-75fc3977b00f.htm) class.

Comment: I already tried that. Wrote the file(header, filename, compressed data and extra length). Then created a fileinfo of it. Got the following error: The magic number in GZip header is not correct. Make sure you are passing in a GZip stream.

Comment: Is your file a Zip file, a GZip file, or something else? You're trying to read it as a GZip file, though it doesn't have the correct GZip header. Maybe you should just read the compressed data portion as a [DEFLATE stream](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DEFLATE).

Comment: It has the PK zip signature. This is the header:

                    // 0-3    Signature
                    // 4,5    Version
                    // 8,9   Compression
                    // 14-17  CRC32
                    // 18-21  Compressed Size        ! Important
                    // 22-25  Uncompressed Size
                    // 26,27  Filename Length        ! Important
                    // 28,29  Extra Length           ! Important

Comment: Ok, you should be reading this as a [zip format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ZIP_(file_format)) archive (I think [`ZipArchive`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.compression.ziparchive%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) will work), not as a GZip archive.

Comment: I used the DeflateStream but it doesn't seem to work because the output is an empty file. When I wrote the decrypted data to the file to make it a valid zip file it was malicious so that's one of the reasons that I want to read the file from the compressed bytes.